# Loop based on parameter value

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I need to create a temporary table that is populated based on two parameters:

```
declare @Start date = '01/01/2015'
declare @End date = '12/31/2015'
```

The temporary table should have a column that will capture YYYYMM for all the years and month that are between @Start and @End parameter.

Here's what I have so far. I want to stop it at 201412 and then start again at 201501.  Instead, this loop keeps going in increment of plus 1 (I do not want to see 201413..so on):

```
declare @Start date = '01/01/2014'
declare @End date = '12/31/2015'

declare @monthstart as int
declare @monthend as int
declare @increment as int

set @monthstart = (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, @Start,112),6))
set @monthend = (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, @End,112),6))

create table #datetemp  (RelevantYYYYMM int)
insert into #datetemp values (@monthstart)
set @increment = @monthstart


While @increment < @monthend
BEGIN 
set @increment = (select Max(RelevantYYYYMM) + 1 from #datetemp)
insert into #datetemp values (@increment)
set @increment = (select Max(RelevantYYYYMM) from #datetemp)
IF (select Max(RelevantYYYYMM) from #datetemp) > @monthend
Break
else 
continue
END

select * from #datetemp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tally table and avoid loop:

```
CREATE TABLE #datetemp (RelevantYYYYMM INT);

DECLARE @Start DATE = '01/01/2015', @End DATE = '12/31/2015';

WITH tally_table AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1000 rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1
  FROM master..spt_values
)
INSERT INTO #datetemp(RelevantYYYYMM)
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, rn, @Start),112),6)
FROM tally_table
WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(month, rn, @Start)) <= YEAR(@End)
  AND MONTH(DATEADD(month, rn, @Start)) <= MONTH(@End)

SELECT *
FROM #datetemp;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412064)**</kbd>